# How to use BigQuery jdbc driver as Solr datasource

Tags: authentication, jdbc, solr, google-bigquery, dataimporthandler

I'm using [this driver](https://code.google.com/p/starschema-bigquery-jdbc/wiki/JDBCURL) with service account authentication.

I've set it up as follows:

```
<dataSource
        name="bq"
        type="JdbcDataSource"
        driver="net.starschema.clouddb.jdbc.BQDriver"
        url="jdbc:BQDriver:projectid(paper%2D48)?withServiceAccount=true"
        username="97838659-sfkvh341gqr77cu08aqcrq15mgec5@developer.gserviceaccount.com"
        password="/Users/joe/projects/paper48/etl/Paper48-2504a86bc2ee.p12"
    />
```

When I try to run the data import, I receive the error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:191)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential.<init>(GoogleCredential.java:279)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential$Builder.build(GoogleCredential.java:414)
    at net.starschema.clouddb.cmdlineverification.Oauth2Bigquery.authorizeviaservice(Oauth2Bigquery.java:206)
    at net.starschema.clouddb.jdbc.BQConnection.<init>(BQConnection.java:213)
    at net.starschema.clouddb.jdbc.BQDriver.connect(BQDriver.java:157)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:571)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:187)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$1.call(JdbcDataSource.java:146)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$1.call(JdbcDataSource.java:133)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.getConnection(JdbcDataSource.java:402)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource.access$200(JdbcDataSource.java:44)
    at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.JdbcDataSource$ResultSetIterator.<init>(JdbcDataSource.java:270)
```

I know the credentials work as I'm succesfully using it to connect to GCS with a boto config file. Could it be that I need to pass the 'notasecret' password for the p12 file?

Comment: I've got the same problem. any solution

Comment: @CarlosAndresGarcía we dropped that idea. We now use python to export it to storage (unzipped csv); then we use `get_media` on the bucket files, and lastly we just send that csv data as is to `/update` on solr. Works like a charm